# Is it necessary to run a SSH daemon if I use Chef locally?

Tags: chef

I want to write a `chef` cookbook to setup Linux desktop environments.

I created a `kitchen` by `knife solo init chef-repo`, and created a cookbook `hello` and a node file `localhost.json`.

Then I run:

```
$ knife solo cook localhost
```

and got this error:

```
Running Chef on localhost...
Checking Chef version...
ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 22
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

Should I run a ssh daemon even if I use chef host and client in localhost?

I'm using `Linux Mint 16` in a VirtualBox environments. And this is my `~/.chef/knife.rb` config file:

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'ironsand'
client_key               '/home/ironsand/.chef/ironsand.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '/etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://vm-mint:443'
syntax_check_cache_path  '/home/ironsand/.chef/syntax_check_cache'
```

Comment: Would you mind asking the same question, as a sample, here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66151/devops ?

Comment: No problem. I've created the example question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tried to use [knife-solo](http://matschaffer.github.io/knife-solo/), a tool that is mean to *"make working with chef-solo as powerful as chef-server"*.  The underlying assumption is, as you found out, that you provision *a different machine* that you'll SSH into.  Knife-solo will then install the chef-client via the omnibus packages (by default), put all the needed cookbooks onto the machine, and finally run chef-solo, from the Chef omnibus package:

From the docs: *"knife solo cook uploads the current kitchen (Chef repo) to the target host and runs chef-solo on that host."*

What you need to run chef-solo is, roughly:

1. cookbooks (probably using [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) and `berks vendor` (v3) or `berks download` (v2))
2. a solo.rb configuration pointing to the cookbooks ([see here](http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_solo.html))
3. probably a JSON file for attribute overrides.

To manage *localhost*, it is enough to get that stuff together and run `chef-solo -c solo.rb -J dna.json`.

Bottom line:  It's not necessary to use knife-solo to use Chef in localhost.